# PHP pack binary data

Tags: php, c, sockets

This is with regard to data sent over a socket to a C application residing on a remote POS system.

Binary data is sent from a php application, in the C app packet structure there is 64bytes stored for a string e.g. a product name.

Now when I send the product name across network through php sockets, I use pack to convert data to binary

```
$value = 'product name' 
$qty = 2;
$len = strlen($value);
$output = '';
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        $output .= pack('c', ord(substr($value, $i, 1))).pack('c',$qty) 
}
```

When the data is received by the C application the string contains a lot of garbage data, including numbers and special characters.

Which of the pack options i have to use to pack the product name into a 64byte binary string that will be interpreted by the C application in the correct format.

Comment: Post the C structure declaration *in toto*.

Comment: Perhaps it expects a null terminated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop to build `$output` produces a string like `"p\x02r\x02o\x02d\x02u\x02c\x02t\x02 \x02n\x02a\x02m\x02e\x02"`

If your C program expects something like `"product name\0\x02"`, then the loop should be:

```
$output = '';
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        $output .= pack('c', ord(substr($value, $i, 1))); 
}
$output .= pack('c',0).pack('c',$qty);
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i had to do to resolve the issue. One was padding the string with \0 as the expected size for each string was 64. and the 2nd step is the same as your code concat the qty later.

Answer (score 0):

Sending binary data through network sockets also may create troubles with byte ordering (Endianess), you might wanna check out if the byte ordering is the same on both systems.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: The Endianess on both systems are the same as the commands used in protocol get interpreted correctly. It only occurs in case of the string data that is passed along.  In case of the data like payload, checksum, command and header the data is passed as pack('N',$data);

Comment: Could there be an issue with utf8 strings, cause all strings stored in my db are utf8 encoding